# What is wrong with my neural network

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, beginner, ai

I have been trying to code a neural network for the last couple of days. I have come pretty far, but i am super stuck right now and am looking for some help to make progress.

I have the feeling my network isn't learning like it is supposed to. Or not learning at all idk.

I programmed everything from the ground up including the matrix class for multiplication and addition.

The most "*impressive*" thing (not really that impressive) that i managed to do is to recognize numbers, but only if i don't use any hidden layers (input -> output). If i add an hidden layer the network recognizes everything just like the last trained number ( last trained number = 0, so from there on everything is a 0). My best guess is that my Backpropagation is broken somehow (not the first step but the others) but i cant figure out how:
( thought for a long time that i am somehow working with the wrong matrices or got some kind of other index fuckup, but in that case i shouldnt be able to multiply the vectors and matrices, because of their different size.

```
// calculate error
        for l in 0..target.len(){
            target[l] = res.res[l] - target[l];
        }

        // create Matrix from Error
        let mut delta = Matrix::new_v(target);

        let layer = self.layer.len();
        
        let mut z : Vec<Matrix<Mval>> = Vec::with_capacity(layer);
        // Calculate all the values before activation function
        for x in 0..layer{
            let y = layer-1 -1*x;

            let lw = &self.layer[y].w;                                                                  
            let lb = &self.layer[y].b;
            let lam1 = &res.nodevalues[&res.nodevalues.len()-2-1*x].clone();
            
            z.push(&(lw * &lam1) + lb);
        }

        for l in 0..layer{
            let y = self.layer.len()-1 -1*l;
            let talm1 = &res.nodevalues[&res.nodevalues.len()-2-1*l].clone().transpose();                   // transposed Layeractivationvalues transpose  
            
            z[l] = z[l].clone().map(Self::derivactivfunc);                                                  // use relu derivation
            
            if l == 0{
                delta = delta.hadamard(&z[l]);                                                              // first round 
            }
            else{
                delta = (&self.layer[y+1].w.transpose() * &delta).hadamard(&z[l]);                          // propagate the error backwards
            }

            delta = delta.mulnum(rate*-1.0);                                                                // multiply the learning rate
            
            self.layer[y].b = &self.layer[y].b + &delta;                                                    // change biases
            self.layer[y].w = &self.layer[y].w + &(&delta*&talm1);                                          // change weights
        }
        
        return self;
```

Im quite confident, that transpose() and hadamard() are correct.

One last thing i am not so sure about is the normalization of my output values before i put them into the softmax function.

```
pub fn normalize( mut vec: Vec<Mval>) -> Vec<Mval>{
        let mut max = vec[0].abs();
        
        for i in 1..vec.len(){
            if vec[i].abs() > max{
                max = vec[i].abs();
            }
        }

        max = max / 2.0;

        for i in 0..vec.len(){
            vec[i] = vec[i]/max;
        }
        return vec;

    }
```

For good measure:

```
    // activationfunction for values
    pub fn activfunc( mut v: Mval) -> Mval{
        if v < 0.0{
            v = 0.0;
        }
        return v;
    }

    // derivative of the activationfunction
    pub fn derivactivfunc( v: Mval) -> Mval{
        if v < 0.0{
            return 0.0;
        }
        return 1.0;
    }
```

I feel like i got a pretty good understanding practical understanding on what every step is supposed to do, but every time i change something either nothing changes or everything and it feels like i am just shooting in the dark.

I would appreciate some suggestions a lot =) Ty guys

One thing i would be especially interested in is a way to check that my back propagation is working.

Comment: what language is that written in ?

Comment: this is rust code